# Most efficient way to assign optional value to a variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I inherited a WordPress project and am currently writing a script to export database tables in .csv format. The original designer stored a lot of custom information about each user in the `wp_usermeta` table. Unfortunately, a lot of this information was optional, and in the case of NULL optional data, the row in the database just does not exist. An example for users with an optional "gender" field:

```
umeta_id user_id meta_key meta_value
1        1       gender   1
2        1       phone    5555555555
3        1       address  "123 alphabet lane"

4        2       phone    5555551234
5        2       address  "123 alphabet way"

6        3       gender   2
...
```

I can't have missing fields with a .csv, or the formatting would look weird, so I need to check each user's info for these missing fields and insert an empty string. Since I will be iterating over tens of thousands of database rows, I was curious which method of variable assignment was the most efficient in terms of memory usage and execution time to do this.

Method 1

```
if (empty($fetched[$field]))
{
    $data[$field] = '';
}
else
{
    $data[$field] = $fetched[$field];
}
```

Method 2

```
$data[$field] = '';
if (! empty($fetched[$field])
{
    $data[$field] = $fetched[$field];
}
```

Method 3

```
$data[$field] = empty($fetched[$field]) ? '' : $fetched[$field];
```

Or are they all close enough that it really doesn't make a difference? Thanks in advance for any insight you may offer!

Comment: They are all condition based so I think that there isn't a big difference in the efficiency of those methods, therefore - I would recommend the third method - short , to the point and without braces.

Comment: I'd normally use the conditional operator, simply for readability. I imagine there's very little difference in terms of performance. [See Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Don't even start to think about the "most efficient way" to do something as low level as this. This is micro optimization and is the root to all evil. Pick the method which you, and other developers that need to look at your code, find **readable**. Just because you might save `0.00000001` seconds, you'll spend twice as long figuring out what the code does if everything is micro optimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They all close enough that it really doesn't make a difference. Bot even slightest.

## No syntax issue ever affects performance

It is

- algorithms (a loop of 100500 iterations)
- data manipulations (looking through a file of 500Mb)
- network lookups (checking RSS feeds for the every page request)
- heavy calculations (image resizing)

affect performance.

But no syntax issue ever. Not whatever syntax issue. Never. Neither measurable nor theoretical difference.